# How do I handle <int, string, int> values?

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Storing string,int,string in an accessable variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567695/c-sharp-storing-string-int-string-in-an-accessable-variable)

I want to handle values like `<int, string , int>` in c#. How do I handle values?

I want to store data in session where there is ID, Name, Type so please suggest me which collection should I use? as I see help for "dictionary" it's store only TKey, TValue.

Comment: What do you mean? Please explain more of your problem.

Comment: Please elaborate more, what you want, a collection a method, what ??

Comment: I want to store data in session where there is ID, Name, Type so please suggest me  which collection should I use? as I see help for "dictionary" it's store only TKey , TValue.

Comment: And then in the future you will want to store id/name/type/nickname/DOB/... The best solution is to create a `struct` or a `class`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While you *could* create a `Tuple<int, string, int>` as suggested by recursive, it would make your code much easier to understand if you just created your own type. For example:

```
public class SessionData
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int Type { get; private set; }

    public SessionData(int id, string name, int type)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Type = type;
    }
}
```

Then you create instances of this class when you need to, and you can store them in a `Dictionary<string, SessionData>` (or whatever).

Creating your own types to encapsulate related data is one of the key tasks in OOP.

Comment: I certainly see where you're coming from, but am I the only one who actually thinks it's often a lot easier reading tuples? As long as the scope is class-only and the naming is good that is. Reading something called "SessionData" requires me to look up the class signature to understand what's in it, while looking at a Tuple<> just requires me to look at the declaration.. Well, I guess that's a topic well worth its own discussion :)

Comment: .. Hmm, just read the question again; I would certainly go for creating a class in this situation as well.

Comment: @cwap: Just to answer your first comment, even though I realize you probably understand it anyway given your second comment: the `Tuple<int, string, int>` declaration will only tell you the data types involved. It doesn't give you any hint as to the *meaning* of either the individual components or the item as a whole. Without more documentation, how would you know which `int` value is the type and which is the ID? Named properties make this much clearer and less error-prone.

Answer (score 2):

`Tuple<int, string, int>` might work.

Comment: Yes, it would - but the OP's code would then make it much harder to read than if they created their own type.